# Question Regarding Linked List and Structures syntax

Tags: c++

I'm aware of the syntax in C++ that ptr->data is equivalent to (*n).data. We dereferenced the pointer in order to add the value ptr is pointing to to variable data, so with this concept in order to add the value stored inside ptr which is the address its pointing to we should write (n).next without dereferencing it, however for some reason it's not working in my linked list code. Is this a wrong syntax or is something wrong with my code ?

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node {
  int data;
  Node *next;
};

void insertbegin(Node *&list, int x) {
  Node *n = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
  (*n).data = x;
  (n).next = NULL;

  if (list == NULL)
    list = n;
  else {
    n->next = list;
    list = n;
  }
}

void display(Node *&list) {
  while (list != NULL) {
    printf(" %d", list->data);
    list = list->next;
  }
}

int main() {
  Node *list = NULL;

  insertbegin(list, 3);
  insertbegin(list, 7);

  display(list);
}
```

Comment: Please tag the question either as `c` or as `c++`. Tagging them with both has to only be done if you specifically ask about a difference between those two languages, or if it is about a question port code from one to another.

Comment: Unrelated: Don't include the `C` versions of the header files. Use `<cstdin>` and `<cstdlib>` - also prefer to use `std::cout` over `printf()`

Comment: `n` is a memory address, literally a number. It doesn't have a `next` member. `Node` has a `next` member, so you need to dereference like you did with `data`.

Comment: `[...]to add the value stored inside ptr which is the address its pointing to we should write (n).next without dereferencing[...]` I don't really understand why you have that assumption. `n` is of the type `Node *` so if you want to access the members of the `Node` elements `n` points to you need to dereference its pointer. So you need to write `n->next` or `(*n).next`.

Comment: It should be  `(*n).next = NULL;` Or `->`. You are dereferencing `n`,  and write to its field `.next` (a pointer) a value without dereferencing  it. A dereferecning field will be `*((*n).next)`

Comment: @FudgeRacoon This question is still listed as unanswered and yet there are three seemingly correct answers to choose from. If you don't understand the answers you can always ask for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `n.next` since `n` is a reference to a pointer:

```
void insertbegin(Node *&list, int x)
    (n).next = NULL;
```

You must dereference `n` first, with `*` or the more common `->` :

```
    n->next = NULL;    // note: use nullptr instead of NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a star in insertbegin:

`(*n).next = NULL;`

You declared `n` as a pointer the line above. A pointer is basically just a number.
If you want to access the Node struct you created you need to use the star or the `->` operator.

Answer (score 0):

The use of `n->` or `(*n).` or even `n[0].` is about how you get to access the members of the object pointed to by n. You always use this form when accessing the members of n, regardless of the type of the member variable.

You use `n.` or `(n).` to access members of a local scope instance of the object or a reference.